# Does not login into account at first time in Codeigniter 3 framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website and login system. In localhost everything is perfect. However, in the server (HOSTGATOR), when people want to log in their account, they type login password and hit "Login" button, it refreshes the page but does not log in. They should enter 2-3 times and then systems logs in. Where can be the problem?

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url', 'security'));
    $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('User_model');
}

 public function login(){
            $data['title'] = 'Sign In';

        $validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

        $validate_data = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'usernameforlog',
                'label' => lang('controller-username-label'),
                'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha_dash'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'passwordforlog',
                'label' => lang('controller-password-label'),
                'rules' => 'trim|required|md5'
            )
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($validate_data);
        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', lang("form_validation_required"));  
        $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_dash', lang("form_validation_alpha_dash"));
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>'); 


            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {

                // fails
                $validator['success'] = false;
                foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                    $validator['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
                }

                log_message('error', 'validation errors' );

            }else {

                // Get username
                $username = mb_strtolower($this->input->post('usernameforlog'), 'UTF-8');
                // Get and encrypt the password
                $password = $this->input->post('passwordforlog');
                // Login user

                $user_id = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);
                if($user_id){
                    // Create session

                    $user_data = array( 
                    'id' => $user_id, 
                    'instructors_slug' => $username, 
                    'logged_in' => true 
                    );

                    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                    $validator['success'] = true;
                    $validator['messages'] = array();
                } else {

                    $validator['success'] = false;
                    $validator['messages'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">'.lang('controller-user-email-error3').'</div>';
                }       
            }

            echo json_encode($validator);
        }
```

Here is the ajax file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginform").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) {
            console.log(response);              
                if(response.success) {
                    //redirect main page
                    location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    $("#loginmsg").html(response.messages);

                    $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
                        var element = $("#"+index);

                        $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .removeClass('has-error')
                        .removeClass('has-success')
                        .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                        .find('.text-danger').remove();

                        $(element).after(value);

                    });
                }
            } // /success
        });  // /ajax

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Post the code of page where login form points.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: Have you tried adding `var_dump()` in a few places to see what the value of variables are and which if else statements the code is flowing through?

Comment: The documentation suggests using `==` for comparison of the form validation `run()` method. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: Where can i use var_dump() ?

Comment: @Goose the function just returns bool so == or === or ! will do

Comment: "it refreshes the page but does not login" ... do you check in your __constructor for this function if the user id or something is set? because otherwise I don't see any logic here to *not* stay on the page if the user is logged in

Comment: I have edited the post @Alex

Comment: Show your session variables from config.php

Comment: `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
// $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_save_path'] =  BASEPATH . 'cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;`

Comment: instead of `console.log(response);` type `console.dir(response);` what is the output?

Comment: whats your destination - if you did log in succesful ?

Comment: just refreshing the page

Comment: Try this in config.php `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/sessions/'; 
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;`

Comment: @Artier it did not work :(

Answer (score 3):

because `location.reload()` will reload your `login()` page, in here you need to add method for checking if user has `logged_in` ?

```
public function login()
{

    $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

    if($logged_in)
    {
        // example redirect to dashboard
        redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
    }


    // rest of code
}
```

instead just `echo json_encode($validator);` better set also your content header as `application/json`

```
return $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($this->response));
```

Comment: It does not log in and also gives a NULL error https://yadi.sk/i/AQGUz6Ip3QwmaH and https://yadi.sk/i/WU8xz2pu3Qwmfi

Comment: can you repost those screenies - because they aren't available any more...

Comment: Here they are: https://yadi.sk/i/d9Trhxrp3R22VG and https://yadi.sk/i/WZBIOD2O3R22XL

Comment: hey did you change $this->reponse to $validator? `return $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($validator));`

Comment: As per your screenshots, it seems ajax is not able to getting response as json. Make sure to get only json from ajax response. Also change value of success to string instead of bool. In PHP make it **"true"** and **"false"**.